# IndexError: list index out of range error

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, minidom

I am still a beginner with python and xml. The following error is bothering me too much. The following is the traceback mess that I get (an error) while executing the following code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path", line 66, in <module>
    print slidename[a].childNodes[0].nodeValue
IndexError: list index out of range
```

from this code:

```
for object in os.listdir(my_directory):
      print (object)
      if '.zip' in object:
            #print (object)
            new = os.path.splitext(object)
            #print (new[0])
            file_name.append(new[0])
            os.mkdir(my_directory+new[0], 0o777)
            with zipfile.ZipFile(my_directory+new[0]+new[1], "r") as z:
                z.extractall(my_directory+new[0])

count = 0

for len_num in range(0,len(file_name)):

    for doc in os.listdir(my_directory+file_name[len_num]+new_directory):
            if '.xml' in doc:
                  #print doc
                  slide_name = os.path.splitext(doc)
                  #print slide_name
                  print ((file_name)[len_num])+'>>>'+((slide_name)[0])
                  file= xml.dom.minidom.parse(my_directory+((file_name)[len_num])+new_directory+doc)
                  tagname = file.getElementsByTagName('a:t')
                  #print tagname

                  for a in range(0,len(tagname)):
                        print tagname[a].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Sorry, we don't do 'urgent' here at Stack Overflow. Can you include a *full* traceback for that exception?

Comment: where does that error refer to?

Comment: My guess is that `tagname[a].childNodes[0]` throws the exception. But that is just a guess, because we have too little information here to reproduce the error.

Comment: You should not loop over `range()`, loop over the lists themselves directly. `for filename in file_name` would set `filename` to each element in the `file_name` list in turn.

Comment: Thanks Martijin         [for a in range(0,len(tagname)):9
                        print tagname[a].childNodes[0].nodeValue I think this part of the code is the cause of the error..Can u please help me fix that one..any alternative way??

Comment: You don't need to "think" what part of the code causes the error. The Python interpreter tells you exactly what line the error was on.

Comment: @MartijnPieters http://pastebin.com/trNVjvUJ HERE IS the link to MY COMPLETE CODE for your reference!!

Comment: @interjay u r right.. :)

Comment: @Sangamesh: I didn't ask for your complete code. I asked for your complete *traceback*. The error you get comes with a details about the call stack, with source lines. We want *that* information.

Comment: @MartijnPietersTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "path", line 66, in <module>
    print slidename[a].childNodes[0].nodeValue
IndexError: list index out of range                                          The following is the traceback message i got after execution...

Comment: @Sangamesh: You can to [edit] your post to add that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I did it...Thanks a lot..I guess i will have more issues since i am starting to learn stuff and i would ask you..hope its fine with you right! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are parsing XML that doesn't *have* child nodes for that specific `slidename[a]` element. You probably want to skip that one.

You are not using Python loops to their full potential. There is *no need* to loop over indices when you can loop directly over the list itself:

```
for a in tagname:
    try:
        print a.childNodes[0].nodeValue
    except IndexError:
        print 'No childNodes for this element'
```